# Where to place the timeout() fadeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, fadeout

function checkSession(){
        $.ajax({url: "session.php", success: function(data){
             if( data == 1){
                var postFilen = 'msg.php';
                $.post(postFilen, function(data){
                $(".msg").html(data).find(".message2").fadeIn("slow")
             }else{ 
                 $('.msg').hide();
             }
        }});
    // setInterval('checkSession()',1000);

Now i want to place to fadeout .msg after 5 seconds it has been shown.
How do i do this..
i have tried:

```
function checkSession(){
    $.ajax({url: "session.php", success: function(data){
         if( data == 1){
            var postFilen = 'msg.php';
            $.post(postFilen, function(data){
            $(".msg").html(data).find(".message2").fadeIn("slow")
                    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.msg').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 5000);
            });  
         }else{ 
             $('.msg').hide();
         }
    }});
// setInterval('checkSession()',1000);
}
```

But then the message wont appear after 1st time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to work with the `delay` method:  http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
 $('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

I your case, something like:

```
 $(".msg")
   .html(data)
   .find(".message2")
   .fadeIn("slow")
   .parent('.msg')
   .delay(5000)
   .fadeOut('slow')
```

[edit: fixed example]

[edit2: new example]

---

This one seems to work fine here:

```
<div class="msg"></div>
<p>
    Some text <br /> <a id="bloup" href="">show message</a>
</p>
```

and then

```
   $(function() {
      $("#bloup").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var data = "<span class='message2'>Hello world</span>";

          $(".msg")
              .show()
              .html(data)
              .find('.message2')
              .fadeIn('slow')
              .parent('.msg')
              .delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
      }) 
   });
```

Comment: Doesnt work.. 1st time it fadeout the same time it was going to show and then second and rest of the time it didnt appear

Comment: Correct, the parent and delay where inverted. Fixed my example.

Comment: Now it do fadeout like it should first time, but second and rest of the time it wont appear again.. Just like my problem was when i tried myself

Comment: Maybe because you use `$('.msg').hide()` but do not use `.show()` afterwards ?  

Since .message2 is contained in .msg, if .msg is hidden, .message2 won't be displayed :)

Comment: ok so i removed the whole else{ $('.msg').hide() } , and STILL not displaying after first time

Comment: Correct :/ Because `fadeOut` will hide the .msg block

Try adding `.show()` after the `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

First try to write cleaner code for us to understand your problem better, your `$.post`'s callback function missing `});` these chars at its end on first snippet on top, and indentation is bad on second.

Then check out these links to understand the use of setTimeout.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

**And to your question :**

if you put `var t =` before `setTimeout(function() {` it would work as expected,

Hope these helps, Sinan.

Comment: why should it work when i make the setTimeout to a var named "t" ?